# number frequence in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset (numeros) like this :

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsFDt.png)

I want to get the most frequent number in all columns.

I tried

```
#through all the columns
for i in numeros[:16]:
print(numeros[i].value_counts().idxmax())
```

and its return

```
1,7,12,5,8,17,14,9,20,2,6,4,14,2,21
```

But this only return the most frenquent number on each column, right?
How can i  get the most 15 frequent numbers considering all my dataset?

Comment: why did you add `.idmax()` at the end?

Comment: @Fozoro to get the number, not the count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `collections.Counter` and its `most_common` method:

```
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (100, 100)))

res = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Counter(df.values.flatten()).most_common(15))

print(res)

     0    1
0   64  126
1   72  119
2    1  116
3   14  115
4   28  114
5   67  113
6   16  113
7   56  113
8   84  112
9    3  112
10  19  112
11  13  111
12  94  110
13  52  110
14  66  109
```

Answer (score 2):

a pandas solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100,(9,15)))
df = df.stack().to_frame('key')
df['value'] = 1
df.groupby('key').count().sort_values(['value'],ascending=False).iloc[:15]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`pd.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (100, 100)))

res = pd.Series(df.values.flatten()).value_counts().head(15)
```

The result will be a series of counts with highest counts first, indexed with dataframe values.